# Rstudio shifted cursor in long code lines

Tags: rstudio

Working in rstudio while suddenly, after writing some lines of code the cursor started to shift, so for example, if I try to delete a character just before the cursor using backspace the character erased is the one before the one I tried to delete. I've read many post in stackoverflow and I tried changing many fonts but it does not work at all.

Comment: Is your cursor in the _ or | position?